# Titanium save file - Could not write data to file at path

Tags: ios, iphone, appcelerator, apple-watch, appcelerator-titanium

I am have created an app with an apple watch extension.

When you click on the button in the watch app an functions gets triggered in the ios app.

In this function i create an json file an send it to the watch app.
When the iphone is not locked everything is working.
But when the iphone is locked i get the following error:

> [ERROR] :  Could not write data to file at path "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4015E77E-A694-4E43-8AF6-4858A5FD5958/Documents/arr.json" - details: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "Sie haben nicht die Zugriffsrechte, um die Datei „arr.json“ im Ordner „Documents“ zu sichern." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4015E77E-A694-4E43-8AF6-4858A5FD5958/Documents/arr.json, NSUserStringVariant=Folder, NSUnderlyingError=0x14dd83fa0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

The stranage thing is, when i try to save data in that file from an remote source it is working, but when i am trying to set an local json string i get this error.

**This is my normal why to save the data:**

```
 var jsontext = JSON.stringify(arrData);
 var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'arr.json');
 f.write(jsontext);
```

**This is the way with the remote data**

```
 var cache = require("ui/common/fileCache");
   cache.loadJSON({
        url : REMOTEURL,
        path : cache.appDir + "arr.json",
        last : false
    });
```

fileCache.js

```
var c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    c.cache = false;

    c.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Daten-Caching :: ERROR :: URL = ' + params.url + ' Error=' + e.error);

    };
    c.onload = function(e) {

        var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(params.path);


        f.write(c.responseData);

    };

    c.open('GET', params.url);

    c.send();
```

I dont understand why the second code works when the iphone is locked and the first one not.

Does anyone knows what went wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason why you save your json to a file, then transfer the file to the watch?  Wouldn't it be simpler to just directly transfer the data itself?

Comment: that is a good point :) i have changed my code to this function Ti.WatchSession.updateApplicationContext. But i would like to understand the probleme above.

Comment: I have no idea but if this reproduces every time, you could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.